# How to represent simple multiplications as additions?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

According to [Kolmogorov–Arnold representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold_representation_theorem) any multivariate function can be represented as sum of univariate functions.

This should hold for multiplications too, so

$xy = F(x) + G(y)$

$xyz = F(x) + G(y) + H(z)$

and so on. Are there any simple examples of `F`, `G`, and `H`?

---

Ah, I thought in

$\sum_{q=0}^{2n} \Phi_{q}\left(\sum_{p=1}^{n} \phi_{q,p}(x_{p})\right)$

$\Phi_{q}$

is a coefficient, while it is a function.

Okay please help to find an example of

$xy = \Phi(\phi_1(x) + \phi_2(y))$

then

Comment: I don't think you've interpreted the theorem correctly.  $y=2\cdot y - 1\cdot y = F(2)+G(y)-(F(1)-G(y)) = F(2)-F(1)$ regardless the value of $y$...  There obviously doesn't exist a satisfactory function $F$ or $G$ that let's this hold true for all choices of $x,y$.  You'd need the $F$ to depend on the value of $y$ in some way.

Comment: The theorem does not say that $xy$ should be expressible with only one sum.